# Is it possible to have a PDF embedded on a webage with a hover magnifying affect?

Tags: jquery, pdf, hover, zooming

Does anyone know of a script that I can use to embed a PDF into a webpage, and have it zoom in on an area whilst hovering over it (like you commonly see on online shops to zoom in on products)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, the PDF is not part of the page. It is in a plugin wrapper. Therefore it is not accessible via the DOM or JavaScript. You would have to write a plug-in for the PDF itself.